# How to test push notifications on android?

Tags: android, push-notification

I am implement Google Cloud Messaging in my application but server side code is not redy. I need some service that i can write my REG_ID and SENDER_ID and it will send me a test push notification, and i will know that my code is written correctly.

Comment: If you must write code to send push notifications anyway, then write it. You can learn to do that for the actual server in the process (if not already done) and maybe even reuse some of that code.

Comment: the samples for both client and server are available [here](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html)  and [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

Comment: Check : http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) provides you enough information about implementing server,you can also test your aplication by using the PHP server side code given in the tutorial

Comment: The link is dead. It would have been useful if you described a bit more what could be done rather than just throwing a link